# How to properly sum and group by, a set of records with where clause in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a table of clients like the following:

```
ID  PNO PID EVENT       GID A     PS
1   04  1   P&R_A       2   1.0   2
2   03  1   P&R(j)      2   1.0   2
3   04  1   P&R(j)      2   1.0   2
4   04  1   P&R(j)      2   1.0   2
5   04  1   P&R(j)      2   1.0   3
6   03  1   P&R_A       2   1.0   2
7   02  1   LP          2   1.0   2
8   06  1   LP          2   0.5   1
```

When I run the following query

```
SELECT PNO,EVENT, SUM(A) AS Atts, SUM(PS) AS Points FROM clients
WHERE ID = 1 GROUP BY PNO
```

I get only

```
    PNO PID EVENT       GID Atts  Points
    02  1   LP          2   1.0   2
    03  1   P&R_A       2   2.0   4
    04  1   P&R(j)      2   4.0   9
    06  1   P&R(j)      2   0.5   1
```

and not

```
    PNO PID EVENT       GID Atts  Points
    02  1   LP          2   1.0   2
    03  1   P&R_A       2   2.0   4
    04  1   P&R(j)      2   3.0   6
    04  1   P&R_A       2   1.0   3
    06  1   P&R(j)      2   0.5   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Event in group by clause.

> SELECT PNO,EVENT, SUM(A) AS Atts, SUM(PS) AS Points FROM clients
>   WHERE ID = 1 GROUP BY PNO, EVENT

Answer (score 1):

You have to add both columns in your GROUP BY, something like:

```
SELECT PNO,EVENT, SUM(A) AS Atts, SUM(PS) AS Points FROM clients
WHERE ID = 1 GROUP BY PNO, EVENT
```

With [GROUP BY](http://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/group_by.php) you group the entries based on the uniqueness of both PNO and EVENT and then aggregate functions (SUM in your case, but also, AVG,MIN,MAX [etc.](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html)) are calculated based on that 'grouping'.

Comment: please explain why adding `EVENT ` in `GROUP BY` clause solve this, thanks

Comment: I was in the process of editing when you posted @MounirElfassi!